# QGIS service area except at intersections with vertices

Tags: qgis, service-area

I have a wastewater pipeline and a manhole layer.
The current pipe layer is made of several lines between manholes (for example at every house connection, with no manhole at these locations). I want to have only one line between every manholes.

My workflow is:

1. "buffer": to create a buffer around manholes
2. "difference": difference between buffer and pipeline
3. extract vertices and select only the ones near the buffer

These three actions prepare the ground to use the algorithm `Service area (from layer)`, to have lines between every manholes.

My main concern is about intersections (this is why I don't simply dissolve my pipeline layer).
When there are no vertices at intersection (as picture 1), the service area is working well.
But if there is a vertex exactly at the intersection (as picture 2), the service area is merging both lines.

Is there a trick to avoid this issue?

[image: Service area is working because no vertices at intersection]

[image: Service area is not working because there are vertices at intersection]

Comment: Sorry, to me, the question is not clear. Can you provide sample data? Can you tell a bit more about manholes and vertices - are they the same? I don't really understand your workflow: what and why you create a difference (step 2) etc.